# JSON API not displaying all values on my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am a newbie programmer, I am working on a website using Django where I use a JSON API I generated online to print the prices of cryptocurrencies.  I am having a challenge as my API is not displaying all the values I want it to display on my html. please note that I've checked with console to ensure the API is working correctly and I confirmed it does but the challenge is I cannot seem to understand why I cannot print it out on my HTML.

Below is my code that I am using to print the prices. The prices that is showing on my HTML is from Bitcoin to Uniswap while the remaining is not showing.

My JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var btc = document.getElementById("bitcoin");
var eth = document.getElementById("ethereum");
var doge = document.getElementById("dogecoin");
var lite = document.getElementById("litecoin");
var bin = document.getElementById("binancecoin");
var card = document.getElementById("cardano");
var xrp = document.getElementById("ripple");
var pol = document.getElementById("polkadot");
var uni = document.getElementById("uniswap");
var btc_cas = document.getElementById("bitcoin-cash");
var sol = document.getElementById("solana");
var chain = document.getElementById("chainlink");
var poly = document.getElementById("matic-network");
var theta = document.getElementById("theta-token");
var shiba = document.getElementById("shiba-inu");
var vec = document.getElementById("vechain");
var stel = document.getElementById("stellar");
var file = document.getElementById("filecoin");
var aav = document.getElementById("aave");
var mon = document.getElementById("monero");
var trn = document.getElementById("tron");
var cron = document.getElementById("cronos");

var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "scrossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Cdogecoin%2Clitecoin%2Cbinancecoin%2Ccardano%2Cripple%2Cpolkadot%2Cuniswap%2Cbitcoin-cash%2Csolana%2Cchainlink%2Cmatic-network%2Ctheta-token%2Cshiba-inu%2Cvechain%2Cstellar%2Cfilecoin%2Caave%2Cmonero%2Ctron%2Ccronos&vs_currencies=usd",
    "method": "GET",

}
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response){
    btc.innerHTML = response.bitcoin.usd;
    eth.innerHTML = response.ethereum.usd;
    doge.innerHTML = response.dogecoin.usd;
    lite.innerHTML = response.litecoin.usd;
    bin.innerHTML = response.binancecoin.usd;
    card.innerHTML = response.cardano.usd;
    xrp.innerHTML = response.ripple.usd;
    pol.innerHTML = response.polkadot.usd;
    uni.innerHTML = response.uniswap.usd;
    btc.innerHTML = response.bitcoin-cash.usd;
    sol.innerHTML = response.solana.usd;
    chain.innerHTML = response.chainlink.usd;
    poly.innerHTML = response.matic-network.usd;
    theta.innerHTML = response.theta-token.usd;
    shiba.innerHTML = response.shiba-inu.usd;
    vec.innerHTML = response.vechain.usd;
    stel.innerHTML = response.stellar.usd;
    file.innerHTML = response.filecoin.usd;
    aav.innerHTML = response.aave.usd;
    mon.innerHTML = response.monero.usd;
    trn.innerHTML = response.tron.usd;
    cron.innerHTML = response.cronos.usd;
});
```

MY HTML CODE:

```html
<div class="coin-list">
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/bitcoin.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="bitcoin"></span></h3>
           <p>Bitcoin</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/ethereum.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="ethereum"></span></h3>
           <p>Ethereum</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/dogecoin.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="dogecoin"></span></h3>
           <p>Dogecoin</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/litecoin.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="litecoin"></span></h3>
           <p>Litecoin</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/binance.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="binancecoin"></span></h3>
           <p>Binance coin</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/cardano.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="cardano"></span></h3>
           <p>Cardano</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/xrp.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="ripple"></span></h3>
           <p>XRP</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/dot.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="polkadot"></span></h3>
           <p>Polkadot</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/uniswap.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="uniswap"></span></h3>
           <p>Uniswap</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/bitcoinn.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="bitcoin-cash"></span></h3>
           <p>Bitcoin Cash</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/solana.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="solana"></span></h3>
           <p>Solana</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/chainlink.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="chainlink"></span></h3>
           <p>Chainlink</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/polygon.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="matic-network"></span></h3>
           <p>Polygon</p>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/theta.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="theta-token"></span></h3>
           <p>Theta</p>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/shiba.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="shiba-inu"></span></h3>
           <p>Shiba Inu</p>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="coin">
       <img src="{% static 'images/vechain.png' %}">
       <div>
           <h3>$<span id="vechain"></span></h3>
           <p>Vechain</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid syntax, but it *doesn't mean what you think it does*:

```
btc.innerHTML = response.bitcoin-cash.usd;
```

It essentially means this:

```
btc.innerHTML = response.bitcoin - cash.usd;
```

The `response` object has no property called `bitcoin`, and there is no `cash` variable.  So this is producing an error.  Open your browser's debugging tools and observe the error(s) on the console.

You can still use a property with a hyphen in it, you just need to use bracket notation to do it:

```
btc.innerHTML = response['bitcoin-cash'].usd;
```